# Saving x, and y from `curve()` in a for loop R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, curve

I have a function called `all.priors` (*see R code below*). My goal is to get the `x` and `y` from the `curve()` call inside the `for` loop, and save these `x`s and `y`s as object `h`.

(I want to have `101` rows, and `2*length(d)` columns in `h`. This way, each 2 columns, contain `x` and `y` from a `curve()` run in the `for` loop.)

**Question:**

how can I correctly save the `x`s and `y`s from the `curve()` call? [I get the error: `incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`]

```
all.priors = function(a, b, lo, hi, d, Bi = 55, n = 1e2){

h = matrix(NA, 101, 2*length(d)) 

for(i in 1:length(d)){
         p = function(x) get(d[i])(x, a, b)
     prior = function(x) p(x)/integrate(p, lo, hi)[[1]]
likelihood = function(x) dbinom(Bi, n, x)
 posterior = function(x) prior(x)*likelihood(x)
     h[i,] = curve(posterior, ty = "n", ann = FALSE, yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", add = i!= 1, bty = "n")
     }
}
#Example of use:
all.priors(lo = 0, hi = 1, a = 2, b = 3, d = c("dgamma", "dnorm", "dcauchy", "dlogis"))
```

Comment: I don't understand what your desired output is. What do you want in each of the rows and columns of `h`? `curve()` returns a list with components `x` and `y`. You can't directly store a list in a matrix.

Comment: @MrFlick, I want to save each set of `x` and `y`, and then plot each set separately?

Comment: That doesn't explain things any better. How exactly do you want the data returned from this function to be structured?

Comment: @MrFlick, I see, so I want to have `101` rows, and `2*length(d)` columns in `h`? This way, each 2 columns, contain `x` and `y` from a `curve()` run in the `for`  loop.

Comment: @MrFlick, do the number of rows and columns makes sense? Do you think storing the `x` and `y` this way would be reasonable for plotting them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to carefully place the values in the matrix, and then return the matrix from your function. try this

```
all.priors = function(a, b, lo, hi, d, Bi = 55, n = 1e2){

  h = matrix(NA, 101, 2*length(d)) 

  for(i in 1:length(d)){
    p = function(x) get(d[i])(x, a, b)
    prior = function(x) p(x)/integrate(p, lo, hi)[[1]]
    likelihood = function(x) dbinom(Bi, n, x)
    posterior = function(x) prior(x)*likelihood(x)
    cv <- curve(posterior, ty = "n", ann = FALSE, yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", add = i!= 1, bty = "n")
    h[,i*2-1] <- cv$x
    h[,i*2] <- cv$y
  }
  h
}
all.priors(lo = 0, hi = 1, a = 2, b = 3, d = c("dgamma", "dnorm", "dcauchy", "dlogis"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way to solve this might be to save the answers in a list rather than a matrix. I think that your function complicates the picture of what is going on,  so I will use a simpler example.

```
h = list()
for(i in 1:5) {
    h[i] = list(curve(sin(i*x), xlim=c(0,6.3))) }
```

The resulting data structure should be easy to use.

Comment: @morouzian  Yes.  Do you want one plot with all curves or multiple plots?